# Reading and writing an XML file using ADF lookup activity

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

We need to read a file and post an XML payload to an HTTP endpoint via Azure Data Factory (ADF). We have the XML file in our blob storage. we are using Lookup activity to read it. And we plan to put web activity after that to post it to the HTTP endpoint. But, the lookup activity does not support an XML output. Is there a way to read a file and send it in XML format to the next activity in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Can you share your  sample XML file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xml()` function supported among Conversion functions in ADF.

Checkout MS docs: [xml function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#xml)

> Return the XML version for a string that contains a JSON object.
>
> `xml('<value>')`
>
> **Parameter:**
>
> The string with the JSON object to convert. The JSON object **must
> have only one root property, which can't be an array.** Use the
> backslash character () as an escape character for the double
> quotation mark (").

### Example:

Sample Source xml file stored in blob storage.

[image]

[image]

**Solution:**

```
@string(xml(json(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]))))
```

[image]

[image]

**Now, you can either use this as string to store in a variable or directly use it dynamically in a web activity payload.**

```
@xml(json(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0])))
```

[image]

Checkout MS docs for more : [xml function examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#xml)

Comment: Thanks Karthik, this seems to be helpful but it seems we have a different XML format.
<Transmission xmlns="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<TransmissionHeader>
<SenderTransmissionNo>12365</SenderTransmissionNo>
<UserName>xxxxxxxxxxxx</UserName>
<Password>xxxxxxxxxxxx</Password>
<AckSpec>
<ComMethodGid>
<Gid>
<Xid>HTTPPOST</Xid>
</Gid>
</ComMethodGid>
<AckOption>ERROR</AckOption>
</AckSpec>
<ServletURL>https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ServletURL>
</TransmissionHeader>
We are getting blank response in lookup for Transmission xmlns. Any suggestions?